# Git repo vanishes in integrated bash terminal in PyCharm when switching to virtual environment

Tags: python, git, pycharm, python-venv

When I start a new terminal by click on the "**+**"-sign, a new `git-bash terminal` is started.
As I am in the root-folder of the currently selected `PyCharm` project, it recognizes automatically the `.git` - folder and checks on which branch I currently am. Here, I was recently on '`release/dev`' (as visible in what follows).

Since the pip-virtual-env was not recognized automatically, I had to source the activation-script manually, even though I'd checked the box in the PyCharm-settings:
[image: activate_virtualenv_in_pycharm]

```
username@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/proj (release/dev)
$ source ../proj-venv/Scripts/activate
```

Next, something **unexpected** happens:

```
(proj-venv)
username@hd1pcms0347 MINGW64 ~/Projects/proj
$
```

The virtual-env called '`proj-venv`' was indeed activated, but the git-repo '`release/dev`' vanished.
Moreover, when using the `git ...` command, it states

> bash: git: command not found

Yet, when opening a new bash terminal, the `venv` is gone but the `git repo` is present, and of course all `git` - commands are working.

**Why do the git repo and the venv seem to exclude eachother and how can I resolve this issue?**

---

**System parameters:**

**OS:** Windows 10

**PyCharm 2021.2.2 (Community Edition)**

> Build #PC-212.5284.44, built on September 14, 2021 Runtime version:
> 11.0.12+7-b1504.28 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 10 10.0 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
> Memory: 2004M Cores: 8 Registry:
> debugger.valueTooltipAutoShowOnSelection=true

Comment: For the `git` command not found, check how your `$PATH` is affected after running `source <env-script>` : run `echo $PATH` in your initial shell, and re-run it after activating your virtual env.

Comment: For the prompt part : check `echo $PS1` before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments, in Python, work *by* modifying your shell's `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment settings.<sup>1</sup>  This is why you have to `source whatever/activate`, rather than just running it.  Running it would create a sub-shell; the script would modify the sub-shell's settings; and then the sub-shell would exit, erasing all the modifications.

Depending on what's *in* the activation script, and what's currently in your own shell's environment, this can break things.  Python's venv-builder tries to build careful scripts, but there are an infinite number of ways to break things.

In this case, it seems that wherever Git is installed, that *was* in your `$PATH` before activating the environment, and not in `$PATH` afterward.  You can view `$PATH` before-and-after to see what has changed.  Ideally, the activate script merely *added* the location of the correct Python binary (see footnote 1), but apparently in this case it also *removed* the location of the correct Git installation.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unix-style shells find programs using `$PATH`.  That is, at the command line, you might type:

```
$ python test.py
```

Rather than somehow magically "knowing" where `python` is to be found, your shell simply breaks up the command-line words into an "argument vector" (`sys.argv` in Python).  The one in `argv[0]` in this case is just "python".  This isn't a full path like `/c/whatever/python.exe`, so the shell now takes the value of `$PATH`, which will be something like `/c/bin1:/c/bin2:/c/addons` or `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` or whatever, and attempt to run a `python` or `python.exe` within each of these path elements as separated by the colons.

Python, similarly, uses `$PYTHONPATH` to set up `sys.path`, which is where `import` looks.  So by setting `$PATH` so that `python` finds a *particular* Python version, and setting `$PYTHONPATH` so that this particular Python *imports from* some particular distribution, the virtual environment has sprung into existence.